# delete html tag with jquery using attribute name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to delete `label` tag with everything inside.

```
$('label.checkbox.inline input:radio[name="'+data.name+'_'+ data.hidden+'"]').remove();
```

And this is html..

```
<label class="checkbox inline"><input type="radio" name="f05_55" value="2/">yes<br></label>
```

Problem that I have is that only an input element is deleted and I want to remove everything.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're selecting the input instead of the label.

You could do this :

```
$('label.checkbox.inline input:radio[name="'+data.name+'_'+ data.hidden+'"]')
.parent().remove();
```

or this :

```
$('label.checkbox.inline:has(input:radio[name="'+data.name+'_'+ data.hidden+'"])')
.remove();
```

But note that you shouldn't put the input inside the label.